# Is there a way to replace /dev/null with an actual file?

Tags: linux, green-computing

Is there a way to replace `/dev/null` device with a regular file (or a device that appends to a file, perhaps)? How much data is written to it?

(This slightly odd question is partially inspired by [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DevNull)..)

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid and someone else understands, but I don't understand why it has the green-computing tag?

Comment: It's in the linked article, solution #2.  Kind of subtle, too.

Comment: Why not just unplug your network from the wall and `cat /dev/null > eth0` with the loose end of the cable in a waste bucket.  Then you can easily weigh all the bits that fill it up on any ordinary household scale ;-)

Comment: @Wil: It was a joke more than anything, see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DevNull that was linked at the end of the question..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would strongly advise against doing so ... depending on your system the resulting file could grow really fast. However, it's quite easy to have fun with a VM.

I will describe how to do this during one session, i.e. everything should be back the way they were after a reboot.

Obviously, this has to be done as root.

First, you need to delete the current */dev/null*:

```
rm /dev/null
```

Then create a replacement file with the same name and some adequate permissions:

```
touch /dev/null
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

You may now visualize what is sent to */dev/null*:

```
tail -f /dev/null
```

Finally to bring back */dev/null* to its normal behaviour:

```
rm /dev/null
mknod /dev/null c 1 3
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete /dev/null and touch it as root, then restore it's permissions.

The special device goes away and you get a file instead.

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

On OpenBSD:

```
cd /dev
sudo mv null blah
sudo touch null
sudo chmod a+rwx null
echo foo > /dev/null
```

Some linuxes AFAIK have special device filesystems - devfs; udev - that may complicate this simple procedure.